# Coating a Perforated Hard board for use as Pegboard above a desk?

Tags: pegboard

I'm currently not in the US sonny options may be limited.

I was hoping to find a white surfaced perforated board that could be used as a peg board above a home/ office desk for organising things in a flexible way. PS: not a garage desk with tools.

I wondered if it should be painted (what kinds / how) or it could be coated with white coating sheet (paper or plastic/ vinyl kind of sticker / sheet)

I'm sharing a front & back pic of the board sample. Actual full size is 4 x 4 feet.

Thoughts/ suggestions/ options / Pros & Cons?

Front 
[image: front]

Back
[image: back]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any paint that's suitable for wood will work fine, though it will absorb a bit more readily. You'll get some raised grain with the first coat, so plan on hitting it with a sanding sponge or similar after, then let it dry well before you recoat to prevent excessive swelling. A sanding sealer might be a good idea to start if you don't mind buying multiple products.

Overlaying adhesive sheet isn't a great idea. It won't bond well and you'd have to punch out all the holes. They do make a white melamine-coated pegboard, though it sounds like it might not be available to you.

Comment: Thanks. The above option of sanding and sealer and moisture seem a bit extreme for where I am. Is there a simpler path? Or I might want to put an adhesive sticker and be done with it.  Simplest path? Is there a simple paint it way or stickers easier?

Comment: The melamine seems tempting, as it could double up as a partial whiteboard? Right? Not available here. Could this board be easily coated with melamine or similar white board like surface treatment?

Comment: I think the holes would prevent effective use as a whiteboard. I know of no way for a DIYer to apply melamine. I've always assumed that it was baked on or applied through some mystical industrial process.

Comment: Well, you are on a DIY forum. Most of us don't consider putting two coats of paint on something to be "extreme". :) You haven't said what you're trying to accomplish in your question, so that's all I have to offer.

Comment: If it's thin adhesive sheet then I don't mind punching the sheet every time I insert something to attach to the board. Side benefit, unused holes don't become space for critters (in Asia now)

Comment: i understand that diy forum. It's little difficult due to where I am lack of places like Home Depot. So, I was looking for the simplest path to set up a board where I can peg/ zip tie stuff on it to save desk space.

Comment: Posting the pic from phone, but will post what I wanted from some online diy projects I saw. Tomorrow morning